# deleting a hook

Tags: vertices

I am running blender 2.91.2 and I don't know how to delete a hook

This is the only object in the scene that is visible so its not from another object

[image]

**[image]**

Comment: Can you share your .blend please? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: shared it thanks for taking a look at it

Comment: Are you talking about that black square top left??

Comment: the exact one right above the seat, maybe its not a vertex

Comment: It's actually at the origin of Empty.003 and you can get rid of it by deleting the hook modifier from the cube (which I've never used so don't know what that will affect).

Comment: Ok so anyone know if there is a special way to delete a hook modifier that is on the cube ?

Comment: If you delete it from the modifier stack it doesn't seem to make any difference to the shape of the object, so I'm not really sure why it's there in the first palce to be honest. Are you following a tutorial or working on your own?

Comment: Oh I can tell you why its there ... I am learning blender lol I am following a tutorial with hope to get to where I can work on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a vertex, it's a symbol for Relationship Lines. You have probebly inadvertently hooked a vertex with `CTRL-H`
You can turn it off here:

[image]

To remove the hook, in Edit Mode click Remove Hook
[image]

Comment: Please consider https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2767/15543 when requesting files.